# How to reduce Android menu response delay?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

i have created a simple android menu, but some how i find it little delay in response , a second or so. Is there any way to reduce the delay in response.

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: are you testing on emulator or real device?

Comment: When do you see a delay in response? Is it when the user opens the menu? Or is it when the user selects an item from the menu?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  : when user opens the menu, it take some time to open it ,  a delay .

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing this. Your XML file looks pretty straight forward and won't cause such a long delay. I suggest that you create a new project in Android Studio and build just the pieces needed to recreate the problem. You should especially concentrate effort on recreating any `onCreateOptionsMenu()` methods you have in your original app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of Android menu. When you handle on item menu click event you can perform operation that blocking MainThread, thus yor menu opens with delay.

For more information read  [it](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)